# How can I connect mail(1) to my Gmail/Yahoo/Hotmail account?

Tags: mail-command

I would like to use the `mail` command in a shell script to automatically connect to my Gmail/Yahoo/Hotmail account and send/receive messages.  How can I do this?

Comment: `mail(x)` doesn't speak any network protocols (IMAP, POP, SMTP). You would need to configure your local MTA (that provides `/usr/lib/sendmail`) to login to your remote account and use it as a smarthost. For receiving, you would need something external such as fetchmail. Use a better MUA.

Answer (score 2):

Also I'd take a look at [fetchmail](http://www.fetchmail.info/). Fetchmail can be used to download mail from POP3/IMAP servers and deliver it locally. There's a good tutorial here to get you started, titled: [Using Fetchmail to Retrieve Email](https://library.linode.com/email/fetchmail).

#### Examples

If you create a .fetchmailrc file in your $HOME directory as follows:

```
poll mail.example.com protocol imap:
     username "admin" password "dir3cti0n" is "squire" here;
     username "fore" password "0rd3r" is "foreman" here;

poll mail.example.org protocol pop3:
     user "betty" password "p1nk" mda "/usr/bin/procmail -d %T"
```

The first rule will poll mail.example.com for mail using IMAP for the users admin & fore and deliver any mail for admin to squire (local user) and foreman (local user).

The second rule will use pop3 and any mail for betty will be run through `procmail` for delivery.

#### References

- [Fetchmail man page](http://www.catb.org/~esr/fetchmail/fetchmail-man.html)
- [Procmail](http://www.procmail.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Anything "mail" doesn't speak imap, which most of the web-based services offer as an alternative.

Consider installing/using mutt.

Answer (score 0):

How about Mutt email client?

Here is a link for tutorial:

http://crunchbanglinux.org/wiki/howto/howto_setup_mutt_with_gmail_imap

Comment: Thanks for the link, but please refrain from link-only answers.  If you have a link but not much else to say, then please create a comment.